# UIView shows 25% of it

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a map with the MapBox library.
Now i set the background like this:

```
    UIView *background = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IGBackgroundView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [_mapView setBackgroundView:myView];
```

NOTE setBackgroundView: aks for a UIView*

This works great, it shows correct.
What i want is to have the background a bit more fancy.
I want to animate it using:

```
animationContainer.animationImages = imagesArray;
animationContainer.animationDuration = 0.5f;
[animationContainer startAnimating];
```

There for i want to make a controller so the nib can have a file owner and there i can add the code to keep things nice and clean.

Now i have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IGBackgroundViewController : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;

@end
```

and

```
   #import "IGBackgroundViewController.h"

@implementation IGBackgroundViewController

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        _view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IGBackgroundView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        [self addSubview:_view];
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

And to set the background i use:

```
    IGBackgroundViewController *background = [[IGBackgroundViewController alloc] init];

    [_mapView setBackgroundView:background];
```

It works but it shows like 25% of the total:
[image: nib and result]

Anyone any idea why this happens?

P.s. i'm pretty new to iOS development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to Autosize!

Probably you have setted something wrong in Interface Builder and when you run the app, the view go in a different position.

[image]

hope this help.

Comment: In the size inspector i can find the "show frame rectangle" origin, x, y, width and height. But the autosizing is not there.